# Taylor series for $e^{-x \ln x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, closed-form

What is a Taylor expansion for the following function?
$$ e^{-x \ln x} $$

I assume you can't do a Taylor expansion around $x=0$, since the function doesn't exist at that point.  The next best choice seems to be $x=1$, since that's when $\ln(x)=0$.  So, when I try to do an expansion around $x=1$, I get an answer that seems to have no clean closed-form ([verified with wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%20expansion%20of%20e%5E%28-xlnx%29%20%20at%20x%3D1)):
$$ 1 - (x - 1) + \frac{1}{2} (x - 1)^3 - \frac{1}{3} (x - 1)^4 + \frac{1}{12}(x - 1)^5 +  \frac{1}{120}(x - 1)^6 -  \dots$$

(Notice the above series has a zero coefficient for the $(x-1)^2$ term...which makes it even trickier to generate a closed-form expression for).

However, I believe this function should be easily expanded and neatly integrated term-by-term (as suggested by the solution to question 1A on this [prelim exam question from UC Berkeley](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F18%20Solutions.pdf)).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You do not need a power series is where you are going wrong. Simply plug in the exponent into the Taylor series for $e^x$

Comment: As Ninad Munshi points out, answering the exam question does not actually require you to find the Taylor series of  $e^{-x \ln x}$. Plugging in $- x \ln x$ into the Taylor series of the exponential yields the expression in Thomas Andrews's comment, and integrating each term will lead you to the identity, which is known as [Sophomore's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream); the proof is described in detail in the Wikipedia link.

Comment: Aha thank you very much!  I worked through the wikipedia proof and I understand it now.  I really appreciate the help.  One lingering question: why is this Taylor series a good approximation of this function, even though the function is not infinitely differentiable (and in fact doesn't exist) at x=0?

Comment: @Jacquerie For a fixed $z$, $e^z = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ is exact, no matter what you plug in for $z$. So for any fixed $x > 0$, the equation $e^{- x \ln x} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(-x \ln x)^n}{n!}$ is exact, not an approximation. However, because we are integrating over $x$, you are right to be concerned that for different $x$, the convergence of the Taylor series may be slower. This is why showing *uniform convergence* of this series is necessary to interchange the sum with integral, as the Wikipedia proof mentions.

Comment: @angryavian Oh I see!  Thank you for the detailed explanation.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{x^{-x}}&=1 - (x - 1) + \frac{1}{2} (x - 1)^3 - \frac{1}{3} (x - 1)^4 + \frac{1}{12}(x - 1)^5 +  \frac{1}{120}(x - 1)^6 -  \dots\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
when expanded at $x=1$,

> where
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(a_n)_{n\geq 0}=(1, -1, 0, 3, -8, 10, 6, -42, -160,\ldots)}
> \end{align*}
> is stored as *[A176118](https://oeis.org/A176118)* in OEIS.